# Establecer conexion entre genexus y informix 12.10

Tags: genexus

Actualmente me encuentro comenzando un proyecto y el problema que tengo al querer conectar genexus 17 (U3) con informix 12.10 es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los pasos que realize fueron los siguientes:

Instale Informix 12.10
Instale el sdk de informix
Copie el archivo IBM.Data.Informix.dll a la carpeta  gxnet/bin dentro de la carpeta de instalacion de gx

esto como se indica en esta guia
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?22750,Requirements+-+.NET+Generator+Manual+of+GeneXus+X+Evolution+2

Que paso me esta faltando realizar?

Agradezco su pronta ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto el procedimiento que comentas que hiciste.
Pero, por la imagen del dialogo que compartiste parece que estas tratando de hacer un "Test Connection" desde el IDE.

Para que te funcione en ese caso, deberias copiar la dll (IBM.Data.Informix.dll) en la raiz de GeneXus.

Comment: realize esta prueba tambien pero sin exito, obtengo el mismo error, trate de enviar un ticket y no tuve una respuesta clara, lo unico que me aclararon es que con ODBC ya no se puede realizar esta conexion